# Replace all collocations in a text file with a dictionary of collocations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, information-retrieval

I'm trying to replace substrings in a text file [corpus.txt] with some other substrings[collocation|ngram] using python. I have the list of possible substrings in a file sub.txt containing the following:

```
dogs chase
birds eat
chase birds
chase cat
chase birds .
```

and a corpus.txt containing some texts as below:

```
dogs chase cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
dogs chase birds
cats chase birds , birds eat grains
dogs chase the cats
the birds chirp
```

with the desired output

```
<bop> dogs chase <eop> cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
<bop> dogs chase <eop> birds 
cats <bop> chase birds <eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains
<bop> dogs chase <eop> the cats
the birds chirp
```

And my python code with multiprocessing (used multiprocessing due to the size of the `corpus` and `sub`)

```
import sys
import string
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import re
import itertools
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable

#corpus_dir =  sys.argv[1]
#ngram_dir = sys.argv[2]

#f = open(corpus_dir) # Open file on read mode
#corpus = f.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
#f.close() # Close file

#f2 = open(ngram_dir) # Open file on read mode
#sub = f2.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
#f2.close() # Close file

sub = ['dogs chase', 'birds eat', 'chase birds', 'chase cat', 'chase birds .']
corpus = [' dogs chase cats around ', ' dogs bark ', ' cats meow ', ' dogs chase birds ', ' cats chase birds , birds eat grains ', ' dogs chase the cats ', ' the birds chirp ']
print("The corpus has ", len(corpus))


sbsx = { " "+ng+" " : " <bop> "+ng+" <eop> " for ng  in sub }
def multiple_replace(string, rep_dict):
     pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k in sorted(rep_dict,key=len,reverse=True)]), flags=re.DOTALL)
     print("replaced = ")
     return pattern.sub(lambda x: rep_dict[x.group(0)], string)

def f(a_list):
    out = [multiple_replace(sent, sbsx) for sent in a_list]
    '''out = []
    for sent in a_list:
      c = multiple_replace(sent, sbsx)
      out.append(c)
      #print(c)
      time.sleep(0.01)
'''
    return out

def f_amp(a_list):
    #chunks = [a_list[i::5] for i in range(5)]
    chunks = [a_list[x:x+5] for x in range(0, len(a_list), 5)]
    print(len(chunks))

    pool = Pool(processes=10)

    result = pool.map_async(f, chunks)

    while not result.ready():
        print("Running...")
        time.sleep(0.5)

    return list(flatten(result.get()))


final_anot = f_amp(corpus)
print(final_anot)
```

I added already initialized `corpus` and `sub` variable (in the snippet above) to show how the code works.  Both `corpus.txt` and `sub.txt` contains millions (200M+ and 4M+ respectively) of lines in the actual setting. I needed a code that can do the task efficiently and I have tried `Multiprocessing` with `pool` but it is going to take weeks to complete. Are there other efficient and fast ways to go about the task??

Comment: Cool project. I don't know the answer, but have you considered using NLTK or similar?

Comment: Wonder if you could combine patterns to do less frequent parses.  I.e. regex_ = re.compile(pat1|pat2|pat3...).  On a hit lookup the match’s replacement in a dict, or perhaps not even needed given your sample.  No, not 4M concats, but even chunks of 10-20 *may* help. There’s a flavor of re.split that keeps the separators.

Comment: I now see you concat. But consider using a split, add, re-join rather than a straight out sub. I believe the split keep separator is `(<pat>)` rather than `<pat>`.  I.e just the extra wrapping parenthesis.  Less mem churning from less string manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recompiling your pattern for every sentence. This takes a fair amout of time.
Instead you can compile your pattern globally once:

```
sbsx = { " "+ng+" " : " <bop> "+ng+" <eop> " for ng  in sub }
pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k in sorted(sbsx,key=len,reverse=True)]), flags=re.DOTALL)

def multiple_replace(string):
     print("replaced = ")
     return pattern.sub(lambda x: sbsx[x.group(0)], string)
```

I tested this with using your sample sentence 1 Million times and I went from 52 seconds to only 13 seconds.

I hope I did not miss anything and this will help speed up your code.

Comment: Interesting. I thought `re` cached something like 100 patterns by default, but you have achieved a nice result here.

Comment: Nice observation and solution here @chefhose. A great improvement I have now! Errrm, do you have anything to say about the multiprocessing part of the code?